# Calculate the time takes to fill a leak tank by a leak bucket

Tags: algebra-precalculus

It takes 2 minutes to get water from a well by a bucket which has a hole.Through the hole, 500 ml is wasted while water is being taken from the well ( capacity of the bucket is 3 liters). A tank is going to be filled by that bucket.The tank also has a hole and 500 ml of water leaks through it for each minute. ( Capacity of the tank is 50 liters ) How long it will take to fill the whole tank by the bucket.

Comment: Is 500 ml leaked by bucket per minute?

Comment: It takes one minute to put the bucket into the well and it takes another minute to take the bucket out from the well.while the bucket is taking out from the well water is leaking.

Comment: What attempts have you made to solve this problem? Where are you running into difficulty?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

1. At max fill-up speed, you add 2.5 L every 2 minutes. How much per minute?
2. 0.5 L leaks out each minute
3. how much is the total water change in the tank every minute?
4. how many minutes are needed to fill 50 L of capacity?